# How to Loop through JSON data

Tags: json, getjson

I have below JSON data extracted from YQL(google search page).
I'm trying to loop through this data(using below code but its not helping) and get each key and its value. Please suggest, how can I get the required key and its value.

Thanks.

```js
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

```js
 {
   "body": {
     "bgcolor": "#fff",
     "script": [
       "(function(){var src='/images/nav_logo199.png';})();"
     ],
     "div": [{
       "id": "mngb",
       "div": {
         "id": "gb",
         "script": [
           "window.gbar&&gbar.elp&&gbar.elp()"
         ],
         "div": [{
           "id": "gbw",
           "div": [{
             "id": "gbz",
             "span": {
               "class": "gbtcb"
             },
             "ol": {
               "class": "gbtc",
               "id": "gbzc",
               "li": [{
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "class": "gbzt",
                   "id": "gb_119",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "content": "Google+"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "class": "gbzt gbz0l gbp1",
                   "id": "gb_1",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "content": "Search"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "id": "gb_2",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "content": "Images"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "id": "gb_8",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "content": "Maps"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "id": "gb_78",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "content": "Play"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "id": "gb_36",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "content": "YouTube"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "id": "gb_5",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "content": "News"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "id": "gb_23",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "content": "Gmail"
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "aria-haspopup": "true",
                   "aria-owns": "gbd",
                   "class": "gbgt",
                   "id": "gbztm",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts gbtsa",
                     "id": "gbztms",
                     "span": [{
                       "id": "gbztms1",
                       "content": "More"
                     }, {
                       "class": "gbma"
                     }]
                   }]
                 },
                 "div": {
                   "aria-owner": "gbztm",
                   "class": "gbm",
                   "id": "gbd",
                   "div": {
                     "class": "gbmc gbsb gbsbis",
                     "id": "gbmmb",
                     "ol": {
                       "class": "gbmcc gbsbic",
                       "id": "gbmm",
                       "li": [{
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Drive"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Calendar"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Translate"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Books"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Blogger"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Photos"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Docs"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "div": {
                           "class": "gbmt gbmh"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Even more »"
                         }
                       }]
                     },
                     "div": [{
                       "class": "gbsbt"
                     }, {
                       "class": "gbsbb"
                     }]
                   }
                 }
               }]
             }
           }, {
             "id": "gbg",
             "h2": {
               "class": "gbxx",
               "content": "Account Options"
             },
             "span": {
               "class": "gbtcb"
             },
             "ol": {
               "class": "gbtc",
               "li": [{
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "class": "gbgt",
                   "id": "gb_70",
                   "target": "_top",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "id": "gbgs4",
                     "span": {
                       "id": "gbi4s1",
                       "content": "Sign in"
                     }
                   }]
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt gbtb",
                 "span": {
                   "class": "gbts"
                 }
               }, {
                 "class": "gbt",
                 "a": {
                   "aria-haspopup": "true",
                   "aria-owns": "gbd5",
                   "class": "gbgt",
                   "id": "gbg5",
                   "title": "Options",
                   "span": [{
                     "class": "gbtb2"
                   }, {
                     "class": "gbts",
                     "id": "gbgs5",
                     "span": {
                       "id": "gbi5"
                     }
                   }]
                 },
                 "div": {
                   "aria-owner": "gbg5",
                   "class": "gbm",
                   "id": "gbd5",
                   "div": {
                     "class": "gbmc",
                     "ol": {
                       "class": "gbmcc",
                       "id": "gbom",
                       "li": [{
                         "class": "gbkc gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Search settings"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbmtc",
                         "div": {
                           "class": "gbmt gbmh"
                         }
                       }, {
                         "class": "gbkp gbmtc",
                         "a": {
                           "class": "gbmt",
                           "content": "Web History"
                         }
                       }]
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }]
             }
           }]
         }, {
           "id": "gbx3"
         }, {
           "id": "gbx4"
         }]
       }
     }, {
       "id": "xjsd"
     }, {
       "data-jiis": "bp",
       "id": "xjsi",
     }],
     "center": {
       "br": {
         "clear": "all",
         "id": "lgpd"
       },
       "div": [{
         "id": "lga",
         "div": {
           "style": "padding:28px 0 3px",
           "div": {
             "align": "left",
             "id": "hplogo",
             "onload": "window.lol&&lol()",
             "title": "Google",
             "div": {
               "nowrap": "",
               "content": "India"
             }
           }
         },
         "br": null
       }, {
         "id": "gac_scont"
       }, {
         "style": "font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em",
         "br": null,
         "div": {
           "id": "als",
           "div": {
             "id": "_eEe",
             "a": [{

               "content": "हिन्दी"
             }, {

               "content": "বাংলা"
             }],
             "content": "Google.co.in offered in:                  "
           }
         }
       }],
       "form": {
         "action": "/search",
         "name": "f",
         "table": {
           "cellpadding": "0",
           "cellspacing": "0",
           "tbody": {
             "tr": {
               "valign": "top",
               "td": [{
                 "width": "25%",
                 "content": " "
               }, {
                 "align": "center",
                 "nowrap": "",
                 "input": [{
                   "name": "hl",
                   "type": "hidden",
                   "value": "en-IN"
                 }, {
                   "name": "source",
                   "type": "hidden",
                   "value": "hp"
                 }, {
                   "name": "biw",
                   "type": "hidden"
                 }, {
                   "name": "bih",
                   "type": "hidden"
                 }],
                 "div": {
                   "class": "ds",
                   "style": "height:32px;margin:4px 0",
                   "input": {
                     "autocomplete": "off",
                     "class": "lst",
                     "value": ""
                   }
                 },
                 "br": {
                   "style": "line-height:0"
                 },
                 "span": [{
                   "class": "ds",
                   "span": {
                     "class": "lsbb",
                     "input": {
                       "class": "lsb",
                       "name": "btnG",
                       "type": "submit",
                       "value": "Google Search"
                     }
                   }
                 }, {
                   "class": "ds",
                   "span": {
                     "class": "lsbb",
                     "input": {
                       "class": "lsb",
                       "name": "btnI",
                       "onclick": "if(this.form.q.value)this.checked=1; else top.location='/doodles/'",
                       "type": "submit"
                     }
                   }
                 }]
               }, {
                 "align": "left",
                 "class": "fl sblc",
                 "nowrap": "",
                 "width": "25%",
                 "a": [{

                   "content": "Advanced search"
                 }, {

                   "content": "Language tools"
                 }]
               }]
             }
           }
         },
         "input": {
           "id": "gbv",
           "name": "gbv",
           "type": "hidden",
           "value": "1"
         },
         "script": "(function(){var a,b=\"1\";})();"
       },
       "span": {
         "id": "footer",
         "div": {
           "style": "font-size:10pt",
           "div": {
             "id": "fll",
             "style": "margin:19px auto;text-align:center",
             "a": [{

               "content": "Advertising Programs"
             }, {

               "content": "Business Solutions"
             }, {

               "rel": "publisher",
               "content": "+Google"
             }, {
               "content": "About Google"
             }, {
               "id": "fehl",
               "content": "Google.com"
             }]
           }
         },
         "p": {
           "style": "color:#767676;font-size:8pt",
           "a": [{
             "content": "Privacy"
           }, {
             "content": "Terms"
           }],
           "content": "© 2015"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: does it make sense now?

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: I wan to loop through this and look for input type "text" or "button" and its corresponding values like javascript function, etc and write a function which will put some value in text box and fire the post method on the form.